# Lenovo touchpad not working at all

Tags: touchpad

I recently switched from ubuntu to windows 10 and everything worked but my wifi for some reason. So i decided to switch back to ubuntu but now my touchpad does not work at all. Even though it worked on windows. I'm so confused please help...

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: And switching OS back and forth because something did not work is not very clever.